# How to use REDHAWK Shared Libraries dependencies with Devices?

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using REDHAWK 2.0.5 on CentOS 7. I am adding Shared Library (SoftPkg) References (for example rh.dsp) to my Device via the Implementations tab in the IDE. This allows the headers and libraries of rh.dsp (located in $SDRROOT/**dom**/deps/rh/dsp) to be found, and the Device builds without issue. However, when the device launches in the Sandbox, an error occurs, stating that /deps/rh/dsp/dsp.spd.xml could not be found. When the Device is launched in the Domain, the Domain Manager complains "error while loading shared libraries: libdsp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

I would like to be able to use the REDHAWK Shared Libraries with Devices in the same manner as Components.

I have no problem launching Components with a similar set up. I have printed out the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the constructor method of Components, and observed that the necessary paths are being set for me. When launched in the Sandbox, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes paths to the dependencies in $SDRROOT/**dom**/deps. When launched in the Domain, the dependencies are cached inside $SDRROOT/**dev**, and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes these paths.

I was able to get my Device to launch in the Sandbox by copying $SDRROOT/**dom**/deps to $SDRROOT/**dev**/. The /deps/rh/dsp/dsp.spd.xml file was now being found. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH now included paths to the dependencies in $SDRROOT/**dev**/deps (to my surprise, this also means the seemingly required pkgconfig file is not determining these paths). Does this mean $SDRROOT/**dev** should have its own deps? Why are the Devices looking here and not in $SDRROOT/**dom**?

Copying $SDRROOT/**dom**/deps to $SDRROOT/**dev**/ did *not* allow me to launch the device in the Domain. It still cannot open libdsp.so.0.

I encounter this same issue with other Shared Libraries as well. This includes my own, and the "rh" Shared Libraries included with my REDHAWK installation (blueFileLib, fftlib, RedhawkDevUtils).

Am I missing something that would allow me to use Shared Libraries with a Device? Or is this only supported for Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REDHAWK shared libraries are really meant for use with components not devices. Consider a setup where your domain is on machine A, and you have several GPPs running on different machines. You don't want to have to manage all the application dependencies across all the GPPs, and in fact some applications may have conflicting dependency versions. These issues are solved by REDHAWK shared libraries. When you launch your application the domain will copy all of the components executables as well as their dependencies over to the GPP and into its own folder. Something then needs to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH prior to launching the executable. This occurs [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/develop-2.0/redhawk/src/base/framework/LoadableDevice_impl.cpp#L431) via the LoadableDevice class.

For devices however they run on a node and are not deployed via the domain. Or started by a LoadableDevice. They are started and run by hand by the user on a specific hardware resource through the nodeBooter executable and a DeviceManager so it is up to the user to make sure that hardware resource has all the runtime dependencies.

If you really wanted to you could build the REDHAWK DSP library and install it into a system directory:

```
  ./reconf
  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --libdir=/usr/local/lib
  make -j3
  sudo make install
```

This will install the DSP library into /usr/local/lib rather than the SDRROOT however it will also put the XML files into odd places in /usr/local which may not be what you want either.